# Python: Double factorial function doesn't work on even numbers

Tags: python

I have defined a function in Python to calculate the [double factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) of `n` using a basic `for` loop:

```
def dFactorial(n):
    sum = n
    for i in range(n):
        if (n - i) % 2 == 0:
            sum *= i
    return sum
```

When I enter the number `10`, it returns `0`. However, for all other values (that are not even) that I've tested, it seems to work fine.

Is there an error in my definition? It seems logical to me; for all values `{1..n}`, if it shares the same [parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)) as `n`, then apply the product.

I'm using `Python 2.7.5`, on `Fedora 20`.

Comment: I don't think it would work on any even number.

Comment: @interjay Right you are. I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Because you multiply sum by zero everytime the number is even (since range starts with 0 in python). What you want is `range(1, n)`.

Comment: @user3467349 Ah yes, I may have read the documentation wrong on [range()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range). It says `step` defaults to `1` if not specified, not `start`. Thanks.

Comment: You can define a stepwidth on the `range()` function, which will give you all required factors (except the initial `1`).

Answer (score 0):

try this code this works for even and odd

```
def doublefactorial(n):
 if n <= 0:
     return 1
 else:
     return n * doublefactorial(n-2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my intention was to use the iterative version instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you were looking for is something like this.

```
def dFactorial(n):
    sum = 1
    #range will start with 1 for odd 2 for even 
    for i in range(n % 2 or 2, n+1, 2):
            sum *= i
    return sum
```

Comment: Quite a nice solution. Also cuts the iteration in half. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for multiplication by 0.

```
def dFactorial(n):
    sum = n
    for i in range(n):
        if ((n - i) % 2 == 0):
            if(i != 0):
                sum *= i
    return sum
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate over the range of (n) only over the range of (n/2), see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your solutions. For the sake of abiding to the nature of the original question, I'll apply the small alteration suggested by `@user3467349`:

```
def dFactorial(n):
    sum = n
    for i in range(1, n):
        if (n - i) % 2 == 0:
            sum *= i
    return sum
```

Answer (score -1):

Even:

```
def dEvenFactorial(n):
    sum = 1
    i = 2
    while i<=n/2
        sum*=2*i
    return sum
```

Odd:

```
def dOddFactorial(n):
    sum = 1
    i = 2
    while i<=(n/+1)/2
        sum*=2*i-1
    return sum
```

Comment: I don't think this is necessary and is essentially a repeat of code. I've not tested it to see if it works, it very well might do, but it seems like quite an obfuscated solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is precisely the equation posted on the wikipedia post. Not at all obfuscated. Look in the wikipedia page where it says "for even n..." "for odd n..."

Comment: Your code isn't tested, and it shouldn't be two separate functions anyways.

Comment: @Sarofeen, for mathematical completeness, the equations on Wikipedia are defined in terms of odd and even separately. However, this isn't required in programming as we are concerned with keeping the solution as concise and clear as possible by minimizing redundancy.

Comment: It was used as a demonstration of translating an equation found online into a code which you seem incapable to understand. Particularly the part where multiplying a value by 0 returns 0. I started by the lowest value of each as a demonstration of a way to avoid your 0 multiplication problem. Redundant code is better than incorrect code.

Comment: You could always do `def dFactorial(n): return dOddFactorial(n) if n % 2 else dEvenFactorial(n)`

Comment: @Reticality Multiple definitions is the problem though. We shouldn't need to define two functions which are basically the same. Even `@Sarofeen` says that it was just to illustrate that I was multiplying by zero (although he failed to clarify how). Never the less, its not good to go down that road.